# Modify Google Apps Script Global Variable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I've been searching for a solution to this problem for hours, maybe I've been reading wrong.

What I basically need is to modify a global variable content, what I've read on [this article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) is that I have to set a property and then I could modify it, but I've been unable to make it work, I keep getting the first property I set.

The first thing I do is set a Property on the top of my script and it does save the Url I'm setting

```
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
scriptProp.setProperty("sheetsUrl","https://**Url1**");
```

Next, I try to modify its content on another function

```
function myFunction(user){
  if(user == "Fredy"){
    var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    scriptProp.setProperty("sheetsUrl","https://**Url2**");
  }
}
```

But once I try to use this variable after "modifying its content", I keep getting the original Url1.

If anyone knows how to solve this I would highly appreciate it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is `var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
scriptProp.setProperty("sheetsUrl","https://**Url1**"); ` located? Is it inside a funciton or alone standing? Form where do you call `myFunction(user)`?Please provide the whole code.

Comment: Provide [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. You are modifying two different variables
One named "sheetsUrl" and the other named "sheetUrl"